# How to get the caret index within the content in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to get the current caret index in content of TinyMCE editor.

```
var caretIndex = editor.selection.getRng(1).startOffset;
```

Also, getting content:

```
var content = editor.getContent({format : 'html'});
```

But:

```
var contentAfterIndex = content.substr(caretIndex, length);
```

contentAfterIndex is not the content after the index, it's different.

Update: By caret index, I mean the cursor in tinymce editor. For example in this screenshot I want to find the text "Please try out the features provided in this basic example." under cursor.

[tiny mce demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWuWB.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some sample content, a sample caretIndex, what you expect the result to be and what you actually see.

Comment: By caret "index" you mean it's position? And what exactly is your question? Title is "how to get caret index"  but you obviously know, how to get its index. If you want to get the word where around the caret, you can copy code from link plugin, cause it gets the word around the caret and uses it as link text.